# How to download my paid or rejected apps ipa from itunes account in AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I want to test application that is rejected or paid application.

I lost my source codes.

The paid application I'll have to buy from AppStore to download. So is there any way to skip the payment for a developer and install the application on any device.

The rejected application also not visible in AppStore, so is there any way to download the application ipa file for installing on any device.

I have access to my iTunes account

Comment: Please provide some more details, what exactly you want.. Download app mean installation in device or IPA or source code of your app or anything else...

Comment: have edited the question

Comment: Downloading your IPA will not help you get your source code back.

Comment: If you still have the IPA, you should be able to use XCode to re-install it on any device that you have the UUID of (assuming your developer certificate is still valid). If you don't have the IPA anymore, I suggest you contact the Apple helpdesk, they may be willing to send it back to you. All that does not bring your source code back, of course, as rmaddy already said.

Comment: I just want to install.  thats it.  no source code is able to get back.  Thanks. I ll contact helpdesk

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

> The paid application i ll have to buy from AppStore to download. So is
>   there any way to skip payment for devoloper and install the
>   application on any device.

You can generate [promo code from iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html), and use code to download for free.

And, your second question:

> The rejected application also not visible in AppStore, so is there any
>   way to download the application ipa file for installing on any device.

You can use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight.html) to install that binary on a device.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: I think, you can't download the plain .ipa file, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: for testflight we again need to upload another build right?

Comment: If previous binary is not expired, no, you don't have to upload another build.